# Menu in title bar for all users

Tags: unity, menu

How may I apply the setting to all users on a given system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your Terminal and enter the following command or open your favorite text editor with root privilege:

```
sudoedit /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.gschema.xml
```

Look for `<key type="b" name="integrated-menus">`. Under this, replace `false` with `true` in the `<default>` tag.

Finally, run:

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```